# Como dar um Nacvontroller.push dentro de um modal

Tags: ionic, typescript

Boa tarde, tenho um model e preciso recuperar valores que foram selecionados para dentro dele, minha duvida é:

como colocar esse código:

```
this.navCtrl.push(ModalAcessoDesktopPage, {
            list: this.lista.selectionModel.selected
          })
```

dentro desse:

```
 this.modalCtrl.create(ModalAcessoDesktopPage,
            {enableBackdropDismiss: false}
          ).present();
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara. O que você quer dizer com "recuperar valores que foram selecionados para dentro dele". Qual o resultado que você espera?

Comment: essa lista.selectionModel.selected, me retorna um array de itens que foram selecionados, preciso retornar esse array em uma outra página que é aberta através desse modal acima

Comment: Tenta isso: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-to-modal-ionic-2/82323/3 adiciona mais uma chave onde está `{enableBackdropDismiss: false}` com o valor que você quer passar.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer selecionar um valor no modal e recuperar os valores quando sair dele?

Comment: Péttrin, quero pegar o valor que já tenho na página, e utilizar ele no modal, a página me devolve um array de itens selecionados, preciso desses itens para aplicar a lógica neles dentro do modal

Comment: Pode adicionar á pergunta todo o código desse arquivo?

Comment: Edson, deu certo o método que me falou, Obrigado !!